# Additional component to linear regulator

Tags: analog, linear-regulator

I came across an additional circuit as shown below. There is no problem how to work as a linear regulator. But it is unclear why does the diode add? What is the purpose of this diode in circuit?

[image]

Comment: Which diode are you referring to? the Zener diode at the bottom or the diode at the left in blue?

Comment: What does "knee" signify and why is there 3.7 volts shown between base and emitter?

Comment: @Andyaka, I think that's a poorly-written "0.7V"

Answer (score 2):

The diode protects the BJT in case of a sudden decrease in input voltage.

If we assume there is a capacitor on the output Vo (as there almost always is) then suddenly decreasing the input voltage to 0V would result in the discharge of that capacitor through the E-B junction reverse breakdown. That can damage or destroy the transistor. Many transistors suitable for this application would have a breakdown rating of 5V and actual breakdown in the 7-9V range, so 12V is more than enough. It would not be useful or necessary if the output voltage was 5V.

It might be better to simply put a reverse-biased 1A diode across the E-B junction because the diode as shown degrades the regulation and does not  protect against a possible bypass capacitor across the 12V zener.

Comment: Thank you. If we add a diode E-C, I think it can protect it as well. Do you agree with?

Comment: Yes, similar to what would be recommended on an LM7812.

Comment: Actually, there is confusion about that issue as well. If we add a diode series with 220R, the current can not pass through input. But the current can find a path though zener diode anyway. Therefore, the current can damage junction reverse breakdown. What is your comment about that?

Comment: What voltage must be at the output for the zener diode to conduct?

Comment: Did you mean output voltage  will be less than zener voltage? So the current flow through zener.

Comment: Current can't flow through the zener from the output unless the output voltage is >17V or < -0.6V.